# axios map through the api response and make multiple api calls

Tags: redux, react-redux, axios

I need to achieve something like below - get response from first api call and get the response - form links and make subsequent api calls while looping through the first response object - the following code works for first call - but not for next calls?

import Request from 'axios';

```
export function getData() {
  return async function getData(dispatch) {
    const { data } = await getDataFromApi();
    dispatch({ type: GET_DATA, payload: data });
    Object.keys(data).map((keyName, keyIndex) => {      
    Request.get(endpoint).then((response) => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_SUBSEQUENTCALLS + keyIndex,
      payload: response });
  });
});
```

};
}

```
async function getDataFromApi() {
  return Request.get(endpoint);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working in the next calls ? What is the error you have ? You have only one dispatch overall ?

Comment: so the initial response object size is 3 - I am seeing 3 times different actions are being dispatched as I am appending the keyiNDEX - but the calls are going through I think I need to wait till each of them completes? thats the part I am missing out here?

Comment: Is it the right way - Request.get(endpoint).then((response) => {

Comment: I have difficulty to understand what you are trying to do because event in the `Request.get(endpoint).then((response) => {`, you loop through all your results but don't reuse them for your fetch. I expected something like `Request.get(\`${endpoint}/${keyIndex}\`).then((response) => {`

Comment: It can be other way also, I am basically trying to loop through the first response object and make sub sequent calls ? How can I acheive this?

Comment: Ok I might know where your problem is from. Your code is in your `actions.js` I suppose. How do you call this method ? `dispatch(getData())` or just `getData()` ?

Comment: I am calling ->(server side rendering)-> static fetchData({ store }) {
    return store.dispatch(actions.getData());
  } from my component and yes this is in action.js

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know where the problem might come from. Maybe from the API ? I really don't know, I won't be able to help you in this, sorry !

Comment: Have you tried `promise.all` or `axios.all`? It worked for me when I was doing something similar in React, no Redux but same idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is my example

```
let getTopStories = () => axios.get('https://someapi.com/v0/topstories.json');
let getStory = ( id )  => axios.get(`https://someapi.com/v0/item/${id}.json`);
let getUser = ( user ) => axios.get(`https://someapi.com/v0/user/${user}.json`)
let consolidateData = ( storyID ) => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {

  let consolidated = {};

  getStory( storyID )
  .then( storyData => {
    let user = storyData.data.by;
    Object.assign( consolidated, { story: storyData.data } );
    return getUser( user );
  })
  .then( userData => {
    Object.assign( consolidated, { user: userData.data } );
    resolve( consolidated );
  });

});

getTopStories()
    .then( res => {
    let ids    = res.data;
    let random = _.sampleSize( ids, 10 );
    let proms  = random.map( consolidateData );
    return Promise.all( proms );
    }).then( storyData => {
    console.log( storyData );
  this.setState({ storyData })
    });
```